# Java Object Marshalling for AWS API Gateway

Tags: java, json, api, amazon-web-services

I'm developing a CLI client application which will use a service on AWS API Gateway. After creating the service, I generated the SDK in the stages tab of API G console. When trying to send a request to API G from Java code, I get an error as "Invalid Request".

I followed the tutorial at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/api-gateway-java-sdk/

I created model in API G with content-type as "application/json" and enabled request validator. The request sent fails validation which I assume is because the Java Object is not marshalled to JSON. The generated SDK does have some marshalling classes for marshalling model object and the request but I'm not sure on how to use them. Any code example with this regard is helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Share your code here.

Comment: There is a marshall method in the model POJO which accepts a ProtocolMarshaller as parameter. I'm not sure what the value for this parameter should be.

Comment: `DeleteRiskResult result = client.deleteDefinition(new DeleteDefinitionRequest());` This is how the delete method is being invoked. An object of the POJO can be set on the Delete request parameter here.